# ICA online learning for large dataset in scikit

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, computer-vision, scikit-learn

I have a large dataset and am tryng to get gabor filters from images. When the dataset gets too big there are memory errors.
So far I have this code:

```
import numpy
from sklearn.feature_extraction.image import extract_patches_2d
from sklearn.decomposition import MiniBatchDictionaryLearning
from sklearn.decomposition import FastICA

def extract_dictionary(image, patches_size=(16,16), projection_dimensios=25, previous_dictionary=None):
    """
    Gets a higher dimension ica projection image.

    """
    patches = extract_patches_2d(image, patches_size)
    patches = numpy.reshape(patches, (patches.shape[0],-1))[:LIMIT]
    patches -= patches.mean(axis=0)
    patches /= numpy.std(patches, axis=0)
    #dico = MiniBatchDictionaryLearning(n_atoms=projection_dimensios, alpha=1, n_iter=500)
    #fit = dico.fit(patches)
    ica = FastICA(n_components=projection_dimensios)
    ica.fit(patches)

    return ica
```

When LIMIT is big there is a memory error. Is there some online (incremental) alternative to ICA in scikit or other python package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there isn't. Do you really need ICA filters? Have tried `MiniBatchDictionaryLearning`, and `MiniBatchKMeans` that are online instead?

Also, although not strictly online `RandomizedPCA` is able to address medium to largish data if the number of components to extract is small.

Comment: Yes, I tried, and it works. (it is commented out in the code above). Just wanted some of the nice properties of ICA for image processing learning gabor filters.

Comment: Another alternative that is currently *not implemented* in scikit-learn (yet?) would be to use [RICA](http://cs.stanford.edu/~jngiam/papers/LeKarpenkoNgiamNg2011) instead of traditional ICA. The reference implementation uses a batch optimizer (LBFGS) but it might be possible to use SGD instead if out-of-core learning is really required.